# JNativeHook and swing - why use runnable in nativeKey* methods?

Tags: java, swing

I am looking at the last example on this webpage http://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/wiki/examples (posted below)

Specifically the `nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e)` method. I stumbled upon this because I was having with the nativehook not initializing properly sometimes in my application using swing; because I wasn't closing it properly in the `windowClosed()` method..

Why do you need to use the `Runnable` in `nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e)`?

Verbatim:

```
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;

public class SwingExample extends JFrame implements NativeKeyListener, WindowListener {
        public SwingExample() {
                setTitle("JNativeHook Swing Example");
                setSize(300, 150);
                setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                addWindowListener(this);
                setVisible(true);
        }

        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                //Initialze native hook.
                try {
                        GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
                }
                catch (NativeHookException ex) {
                        System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
                        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
                        ex.printStackTrace();

                        System.exit(1);
                }

                GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(this);
        }

        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                //Clean up the native hook.
                GlobalScreen.unregisterNativeHook();
                System.runFinalization();
                System.exit(0);
        }

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) { /* Unimplemented */ }
        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) { /* Unimplemented */ }
        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) { /* Unimplemented */ }
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) { /* Unimplemented */ }
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) { /* Unimplemented */ }

        public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This will run on Swing's Event Dispatch Thread.");
                                }
                        });
                }
        }

        public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) { /* Unimplemented */ }
        public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) { /* Unimplemented */ }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                                new SwingExample();
                        }
                });
        }
}
```

Comment: It's most likely that the notification of the key event is not done within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. It would also prevent it from starving the hook thread while you block waiting for the user to respond...

Answer (score 1):

Their could be any number of reasons.

The main reasons would be the fact that the native hook is likely using its own thread to monitor input. Because Swing is a single threaded framework, you need to resync the output back to this thread (aka The Event Dispatching Threading).

You probably also want to avoid blocking the native hook thread as well, so it can continue to respond to input

Comment: Say I have a class that extends `JFrame` and also implements `NativeKeyListener`, say I also have the `nativeKeyReleased` method implemented as in the question, could I call a method or set variables that the class owns within the `Runnable` in `nativeKeyReleased`?

Comment: Yes.  You could change the state of just about any variable you want, the question then becomes, is that variable important to the state of the UI.  If it is, you should do it from within the context of the EDT and you should also try not to block either of these two threads if you can avoid it...

Comment: MadProgrammer is correct, the hook thread does not operate on the swing dispatch thread so you need to wrap it if you want to interact with swing.  This has been addressed with an event dispatcher in version 1.2.  Please see the Working with Swing section in the wiki for more info.